# How can i open records only related to specific parent record using button clicking in odoo 10?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, odoo

How to open a records belong to parent record instead of all showing on view(tree / list) in odoo.
I am having situation where i need to open records for example:

When i select specific Degree /Course (view 1), in the response (view 2) show all subjects regarding to that course / Degree and so on (students assigned that subjects).

Is there any use of context and domain filter ?

Please guide me how to use context and filter in this situation..

Comment: Can you paste the code of the action where you open the tree (the one you need to be filtered)?

Comment: Here is the code where i need to show all students against Subject.

<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="act_open_students_view">
            <field name="name">Students</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="res_model">op.student.course</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">kanban,form,search</field>
            <field name="domain">[]</field>
            <field name="context">{}</field>
        </record>

Comment: Above is view 2 where i need to show all students...

Comment: did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

So as I don't know how you named your variables, let's suppose that the model `student` has a Many2one field named `degree_id`, and in students there is a One2many field named `degree_ids` (although with this context a Many2many relationship would make more sense).

Your action, the one which opens the students tree after clicking on a button in a degree view, should be like this:

```
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="act_open_students_view">
    <field name="name">Students</field> <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">op.student.course</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">kanban,form,search</field>
    <field name="domain">[('degree_id', '=', active_id)]</field>
    <field name="context">{'default_degree_id': active_id}</field>
</record>
```

The `domain` will apply the filter to show only the students who are coursing the specific degree.
The `context` (combined with `default_degree_id` field) will fill in automatically the field `degree_id` with the right ID. I mean, if you want to see students who are coursing *I.T.*, you go to degree *I.T.* view, click on `Students` button, and see the students, but if you click on create, the `degree_id` field would be automatically filled in with *I.T.*, which makes sense.

If the relationship between degrees and students were a Many2many, you must call a server action which is a bit complicated than this simple code. Let me know what you have.